# how to save file from html to pdf

Tags: java, jsp

```
String w=request.getParameter("fpath");

try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(w);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line.trim());
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
     OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\Test.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
    document.open();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(result));
   response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\""); 
   response.setContentType("application/pdf");


    document.close();
    file.flush();   
}


catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is My code to save html to Pdf file But when I click On save as Button it save to E:\Test.pdf  ,while I don't want to set E:\Test.pdf Physical path I want that if user will click On save Button then it should ask where u need to save if user will select that location Then it save to that place    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\""); 
       response.setContentType("application/pdf"); I dont know how to set file name and file content to this so that i can able to save my pdf file to desire location.

Comment: ideally the file would be downloaded in default browser download location right ?

Comment: @anil as vels4j said,it depends on the client side browser where he/she wants to save the file

Comment: yes currently it save to E:Test.pdf i dont want to do i want if click on save  then it should save to download location

Comment: i am unable to set the response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\""); 
   response.setContentType("application/pdf");

 so that i can view that save PDf

Comment: www.indianrail.gov.in/between_Imp_Stations.html  take this file and save to pdf using mY code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of creating a new `FileOutputStream` use the `response.getOutputStream()`. Apart from setting the headers you are not sending anything else in the response

Comment: `PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());`